# deploying a project to wildfly server getting issues with required service are not installed

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8, wildfly-10, wildfly-9

I have created the maridb folder inside Wildfly/module.../mariadb/ and added the required module.xml file and appropriate jar file.

```
08:36:58,152 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("data-source" => "dgpa")
    ]) - failure description: {
        "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mariadb-java-client-2_3_0_jar"],
        "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
            "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/Archive is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mariadb-java-client-2_3_0_jar]",
            "org.wildfly.data-source.dbpa is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mariadb-java-client-2_3_0_jar]"
        ]
    }
    08:36:58,192 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("data-source" => "dbagpa")
    ]) - failure description: {
        "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
            "jboss.jdbc-driver.mariadb-java-client-2_3_0_jar",
            "jboss.jdbc-driver.mariadb-java-client-2_3_0_jar"
        ],
        "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
            "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/Archive is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mariadb-java-client-2_3_0_jar]",
            "org.wildfly.data-source.dbpa is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mariadb-java-client-2_3_0_jar]",
            "org.wildfly.data-source.dbpa is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mariadb-java-client-2_3_0_jar]"
```

Comment: Does your code use a persistence unit?  It's usually in `persistence.xml`.  If so, that must be installed in Wildfly before you deploy your web app.

Comment: this application is running at one server i modified my standalone.xml according getting the above mentioned errors. i will check for persistence.xml

Comment: @stdunbar-i am not sure about the that as this is application is given to our department i compiled it and generated the .war file. should i check the persistance.xml file in war file i generated

Comment: Well you've messed up the `standalone.xml` file now.  You should never modify this file by hand.  Can you post what you were trying to add to standalone.xml?

Comment: @stdunbar: i have added above what i have modified in the stanalone.xml

Comment: This is in the end of standalone.xml<deployments>
        <deployment name="mariadb-java-client-2.6.0.jar" runtime-name="mariadb-java-client-2.6.0.jar">
            <content sha1="7ada3fc7b30ae8fa4616f47ef6d505bdda933605"/>
        </deployment>

Comment: Is your driver, `org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`, defined?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins my module.xml file is this: <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.mariadb">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mariadb-java-client-2.3.0.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
location /home/user/WILDFLY_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/com/mariadb/main and also the jar file in same folder

Comment: Is it defined in the `<drivers>` section though in the standalone.xml?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins,no its not defined anywhere else.

Comment: That may be what you're missing. It's best to use CLI as @stdunbar says. Have a look at this PostgreSQL example https://gist.github.com/jamezp/3d3fe3bf57fe99ea91c1.

Comment: @James actually  I am not quite sure where to add this and I have little knowledge on this as I just started today. Is mariadb folder contents looks ok nd now I only have to fix standalone.xml.???

Comment: No. You need to install a mariadb module, which given the comment above I assume you've done. Then you need to install the driver based on that module. Finally you can create the data source based on the driver. Editing the XML is not advised and you should use CLI or the web console.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, i corrected the issues with standalone.xml i am not understanding why i am getting the issues with the jar dependency i have added at right places.

Comment: and i have also added the mariadb source jar via console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting answer to my question, I messed up with my standalone.xml and I followed the below-mentioned link and it worked.

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBEAP-2405